# Making a partial array in Perl6

Tags: arrays, raku

Is there a nice way to get a partial Array derived from another Array?

Example: given an array with x number of elements, and an `Int $index` within the range of elements of that Array, I would like to run a function from `$index + 1` to number of elements - 1.

Essentially I would like to compare all elements within the Array. Compare being a function of the element itself. (Note I am aware of the function `eqv`, though this is not suitable for this particular situation)

I was thinking of something in the likes of:

```
for $!my-array.kv -> $index, $element
{
    for $!my-array[$index+1 .. .elems-1] -> $another-element
    {
        $element.compare($another-element)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a [Whatever object](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Whatever) to indicate the last array index: `@array[$index+1 .. *]`

Comment: Another alternative is to use [`combinations`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/combinations): `for @array.combinations: 2 -> ($element1, $element2) { ... } `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.elems - 1` calls a method on `$_`, which is probably wrong.
If you are going to write it that way `$!my-array.elems - 1`, or you could give it a lambda `*.elems - 1`. The usual lambda is `* - 1` (an Array numifies to the number of elements).
In this case I would just use a Whatever `*`.

```perl6
$!my-array[$index + 1 .. *]
```

---

To get `for` to return a result, prefix it with `do`.

```perl6
my @result = do for $!my-array.kv -> $index, $element
{

    do for $!my-array[$index + 1 .. *] -> $another-element
    {
        $element.compare($another-element)
    }
}
```

---

It might be clearer to use `map`

```perl6
$!my-array.kv.map: -> $index, $element {

  $!my-array[$index + 1 .. *].map: -> $another-element {

    $element.compare($another-element)
  }
}
```

---

Since you mention that `eqv` isn't suitable, that leads me to believe that `.compare` returns `True` when they are equivalent, and `False` otherwise.
So then `eqv` **is actually suitable**. You just have to adjust it first.

```perl6
class Foo {
    method compare (Foo:D: Foo:D $other ) {…}
    …
}

# this gets mixed into the existing &infix:«eqv»
# mark it for export so that it is available in other code units
multi sub infix:«eqv» ( Foo:D \left, Foo:D \right ) is export {

  left.compare(right)

}
```

```perl6
# must import it everywhere you want the special cased &infix:«eqv»
# as operators are lexically scoped
use Foo;

$!my-array.kv.map: -> $index, $element {
    # cross using &infix:«eqv»
    $element X[eqv] $!my-array[$index + 1 .. *]
}
```

You could also use `«eqv«` (`<<eqv<<`).

---

What you wrote happens to coincide fairly closely with `combinations`.

```perl6
my @result = $!my-array.combinations(2).map(
  -> ( $a, $b ) { $a eqv $b }
)
```

This produces a flat list.

```perl6
< a b c d e >.combinations(2).map: -> ($element, $another-element){
    $element cmp $another-element
}
# (Less,Less,Less,Less,Less,Less,Less,Less,Less,Less)
```

While the previous code produces a list of lists. (with an extra empty one)

```perl6
my @a = < a b c d e >;
say @a.kv.map: -> $index, $value {
  @a[$index ^.. *].map: $value cmp *
}
# (
#   (Less,Less,Less,Less),
#   (Less,Less,Less),
#   (Less,Less),
#   (Less,),
#   (),
# )
```

---

Note that you can spell the name of the infix operator `eqv` in several ways

```perl6
&infix:«  eqv  »
&infix:<  eqv  >
&infix:[ 'eqv' ]
&[eqv]
```

All but the last one can be used when declaring a new `multi sub` implementation.
(after removing the `&`)

---

P.S. I think a method named `.compare` should return an `Order` (`Less`,`Same`,`More`).
So then the correct operator to adjust would be `&infix:«cmp»`.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the double `for` loop by use [`combinations`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/combinations). Assuming you do not want to record the indices, it can be as simple as:

```
for @($!my-array).combinations: 2 -> ( $element, $another-element ) {
    $element.compare($another-element);
}
```